# Dynamic Dictionary and assigning values to variables

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

the program here takes the amount of people buying the item on the top line and that is what determines how long the dictionary is, I want to somehow use / access the items in the dictionary and allow me to manipulate them individually with operators etc later in the code

Thank you

```
GroupNo = int(input("How many people are buying?"))
Gs = int(input("How many  are you picking up?")) 
Ps = int(input("How much money is being paid?"))
PPG = Ps / Gs
print ("Price per  is:" ,"£",PPG,)

def PsPerPerson():
    payments = dict()
    for i in range(1, GroupNo + 1):
        value = input(f"How Much is person {i} paying:")
        payments[i] = int(value)
    print (payments)
    print(payments[1])
    print(len(payments))    
    ListLen = len(payments)
    print(ListLen)

PsPerPerson()
```

Comment: just define 'payments' outside of your function PsPerPerson()

Comment: whenever i try this i get a ["function' object is not subscriptable] error